# A problem Dealing with Sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Below is a problem from the Schaum book: "Probability and Statistics". I started
the problem but I am confident that I am on the wrong approach. I am hoping somebody will tell me where I went wrong.
Problem:
An urn holds $60$ red marbles and $40$ white marbles. Two sets of $30$ marbles are drawn with replacement
from the urn, and their color is noted. What is the probability that the two sets differ by $8$ or more red marbles.
Answer:
First we note that both sets should have a mean of $0.4*30 = 7.5$ white marbles. Let $X$ be a random variable
whose value is $1$ if on a single draw the marble is red and $0$ if the marble is white.
\begin{align*}
u_x &= \frac{3}{5} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= E(X^2) - u_x^2 \\
E(X^2) &= \frac{3}{5} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= \frac{3}{5} - \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^2  = \frac{15}{25} - \frac{9}{25} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= \frac{6}{25} \\
\sigma_s^2 &= \frac{\sigma_x^2}{n} \\
n &= 30 \\
\sigma_s^2 &= \frac{\frac{6}{25}}{30} = \frac{3}{25(15)} \\
\sigma_s^2 &= \frac{1}{125} \\
\sigma_s &= \frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}} \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer to the problem is $0.0482$ and I am confident that my work is wrong. Please tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Based upon the response I received, I have been able to continue my work. However, I am stuck. Here is my updated work:

\begin{align*}
u_x &= \frac{3}{5} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= E(X^2) - u_x^2 \\
E(X^2) &= \frac{3}{5} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= \frac{3}{5} - \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^2  = \frac{15}{25} - \frac{9}{25} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= \frac{6}{25} \\
\sigma_s^2 &= n \sigma_x^2 \\
n &= 30 \\
\sigma_s^2 &= 30 \left( \frac{6}{25} \right) = \frac{6(6)}{5} \\
\sigma_s^2 &= \frac{36}{5} \\
\sigma_s &= \frac{6}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\end{align*}
Let $SD$ be the number of standard deviations $8$ marbles is.
\begin{align*}
SD &= \frac{8}{ \frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}  } = \frac{8\sqrt{5}}{6} \\
SD &= \frac{4 \sqrt{5}}{3} \doteq 2.981424 \\
\end{align*}
At this point, I am not sure what to do.
Bob

Answer (score 1):

The sample variance is $n$ times the variance of one marble.  This makes $\sigma_s^2=\frac {36}{5}$.  The variance of the difference of two samples is twice the variance of one, so $\frac{72}5$.  The square root of this is about $3.79$, so a difference of $8$ is about $2$ standard deviations.

Comment: Milikan I am finding your answer incomplete. Can you show me how to get to the final answer.

Comment: You missed the point that you have two normal distributions that you are taking the difference of, so the variance of the difference is twice the variance of one distribution.  That accounts for a factor $\sqrt 2$ in the standard deviation of the difference and then the difference between my about $2$ and your $2.98$.  Once you recognize that, you can look up the correct number of standard deviations in your z-score table to find the chance the difference exceeds 8